# C++ - Read from file to std vector with vector<>.data() using file.read()

Tags: c++, file, stdvector

I am trying to read data from a file and put it into a `vector<unsigned char>` using the `file.read()` method, but something goes wrong.

```
typedef unsigned char BYTE;
#include <fstream>
#include <string.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

    class ROM{
        private:
            std::vector<BYTE> RomName;        

        public:
            ROM (const char* t_RomFileName){                
                std::ifstream ROMFile(t_RomFileName, std::ifstream::ate | std::ifstream::binary);
                RomName.reserve(16);

                if (ROMFile.is_open()){
                    size = ROMFile.tellg();
                    ROMFile.seekg (80, ROMFile.beg);
                    ROMFile.read((char*)RomName.data(), 16); 

                    for(std::vector<BYTE>::iterator it = RomName.begin(); it != RomName.end(); ++it ){
                        std::cout << *it;
                    }
                    ...
                }
     };
```

Nothing is printed on the screen and the `RomName.size()` returns `0`.  Also, the file pointer moved of 16 bytes. I tried with `char* test = new char[16]` and reading in it all works. Where I wrong?

Comment: you have to write `RomName.resize(16)`.  Writing `RomName.reserve(16)` does not change the size of `RomName` by constructing 16 `BYTE`s - it just places it into an allocated memory region where 16 `BYTE`s can be pushed onto it without re-allocating.  Also your `seekg` call does not match your comment - 0x100 has decimal value 256.

Comment: @jcarpenter2 what a stupid!!! Thank you!! I did not notice the mistake!! 
Yes, I edited my code to write this question and I did not delete the comments! (deleted now).

Comment: did you see the part about using `resize` and not `reserve`?

Comment: yes! Now all work correctly